# How can I group data by id and get the median value using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, databricks

I have a table with the time a given store opened during a couple of days, like you can see below (OPENING_HOUR is set as 24h time format, so all the hours on the table are AM).

```
>>> BUSINESS_HOURS
    DATE       | STORE_ID | OPENING_HOUR
________________________________________
0   2021-06-01 |   222    |  11
1   2021-06-02 |   222    |  11
2   2021-06-03 |   222    |  11
3   2021-06-04 |   222    |  11
4   2021-06-05 |   222    |  11
5   2021-06-06 |   222    |  11
6   2021-06-07 |   222    |  12
7   2021-06-08 |   222    |  11
8   2021-06-09 |   222    |  11
9   2021-06-10 |   222    |  12
```

Now I need to group the data by id and tell which opening_hour was most frequent. In the case bellow, 11am was present in 80% of the cases, so I need something like this:

```
>>> DATA_GROUPED
    STORE_ID   | OPENING_HOUR | FREQUENCY
________________________________________
0   222        |   11         |  0.8
```

Is that possible using only SQL? Thank you for your help, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select store_id, opening_hour, count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
where store_id = 1
group by store_id, opening_hour
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

If you want this for all stores, you can use window functions:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select store_id, opening_hour, count(*) as cnt,
            count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio,
            row_number() over (partition by store_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
     from t
     group by store_id, opening_hour
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an way by using window functions and CTEs.

```
WITH Q1 AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT STORE_ID,
    OPENING_HOUR,
    COUNT(OPENING_HOUR) AMOUNT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STORE_IDORDER BY COUNT(OPENING_HOUR) DESC) as RANK
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)

SELECT
  STORE_ID,
  OPENING_HOUR,
  ROUND((AMOUNT/SUM(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY STORE_ID)),2) AS SHARE
FROM Q1-- WHERE RANK = 1
```

Not the shortest answer out there but it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

With windowing function, this one solution:

```
WITH business_hours as (
SELECT DATE("2021-06-01") as date, 222 as store_id, 11 as opening_hour
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-02", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-03", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-04", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-05", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-06", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-07", 222, 12
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-08", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-09", 222, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-06-10", 222, 12)

, agg as (SELECT DISTINCT store_id, opening_hour,
COUNT(store_id) OVER (partition by opening_hour, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)) as total_open_per_hour,
COUNT(store_id) OVER (partition by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)) as total_open,
from business_hours)

SELECT store_id, opening_hour, safe_divide(total_open_per_hour, total_open) frequency FROM agg
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select distinct store_id, opening_hour, 
    count(1) over(partition by opening_hour) / count(1) over() frequency
  from business_hours
)
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by store_id order by frequency desc) = 1
```

gives you the most frequent opening_hour per store

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]